# How to avoid "Recompile with -xLint:unchecked" in this example

Tags: java

When I compile my class I get these warnings:

> Note: JSONLoader.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations
>
> Note: Recompile with -xLint:unchecked

The class is as simples as:

```
class JSONLoader<T>{
    public T loads(String file_name){
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = null;
        try{
            obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(file_name));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return (T) obj;
    }
}
```

I should add, that this class should return either `JSONObject` or `JSONArray` (depending on the contents of the file) and these object types are incompatible.

Comment: The easiest way would be to suppress the warning.

Comment: @Thomas. I do not like suppressing warnings )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with your approach you could use `JSONObject x = loader.loads(filename)` and the file actually returns a `JSONArray`. In your case the type of `T` is inferred from the assignment of the return value and this information will be lost at runtime.

I'd say you'd better add two methods which define one of the two types as return value and check whether the file contents matches (you can't do that with your approach since you can't determine the type of `T`).

Example:

```
JSONObject loadObject( String filename ) {
  ...

  Object obj = parser.parse( xxx );
  if( obj instanceof JSONObject ) {
    return (JSONObject)obj;
  }
  else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException( "json root is not a single object");
  }
}

JSONArray loadArray(String filename) {
  //similar to above
}
```

Alternatively, e.g. if you want a single method, you could create a wrapper that allows for one of the two types (e.g. via constructor overload) and put the checks into that wrapper (or provide sth. like `isArray()` etc.).